# ¿Como puedo usar un Trigger para act. la hoja de costos en base al material utilizado, adornos y los días de trabajo prog. para la const. del jardín?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create database bd_jardines;
use bd_jardines;
go



create table tipoCliente(
idTipoCliente varchar(50) not null,
tipoCliente varchar(50) not null,
constraint pk_tipoCliente primary Key(idTipoCliente)
);


create table Cliente(
nombreUsuario varchar(50) not null,
nombres varchar(50) not null,
apellidos varchar (50) not null,
contraseña varchar(100) not null,
idTipoCliente varchar(50) not null,

constraint pk_Cliente primary key(nombreUsuario),
constraint fk_tipoCliente  foreign key(idTipoCliente) 
references tipoCliente(idTipoCliente) on update cascade on delete cascade

);

create table Pedido(
codPedido varchar(50) not null,
nombreUsuario varchar(50) not null,
constraint pk_pedido primary key(codPedido)


);

create table Dimension(
idDimension varchar(50) not null,
largo int not null,
ancho int not null,

constraint pk_dimension primary key(idDimension)
);


create table detalle_pedido(
codPedido varchar(50) not null,
idDimension varchar(50) not null,
montoEstimado money  not null,
descripcion varchar(150) ,

constraint pk_detalle_pedido primary key(codPedido),
constraint fk_codPedido foreign key(codPedido) 
references pedido(codPedido) on update cascade on delete cascade,
constraint fk_dimension foreign key(idDimension)
references dimension(idDimension) on update cascade on delete cascade

);


create table Planta(
codPlanta varchar(50) not null,
planta varchar(50)  not null,
precioUnidad money not null,

constraint pk_planta primary key(codPlanta)


);

create table pedido_planta(
codPedido varchar(50) not null,
codPlanta varchar(50)  not null,
cantidad int not null,

constraint pk_pedido_planta primary key(codPedido,codPlanta),
constraint fk_pedidoCod  foreign key(codPedido)
references pedido(codPedido) on update cascade on delete cascade,
constraint fk_plantaCod foreign key(codPlanta)
references planta(codPlanta) on update cascade on delete cascade

);

create table adorno(
codAdorno varchar(50) not null,
adorno varchar(50) not null,
preciounidad money not null,

constraint pk_Adorno primary key(codAdorno)


);

create table pedido_adorno(
codPedido varchar(50) not null,
codAdorno varchar(50) not null,
cantidad int not null,
constraint pk_pedido_adorno primary key(codPedido,codAdorno),
constraint fk_codigoPed  foreign key(codPedido)
references pedido(codPedido) on update cascade on delete cascade,
constraint fk_codigoPlant foreign key(codAdorno) 
references adorno(codAdorno) on update cascade on delete cascade

);


create table Experto(
idExperto varchar(50) not null,
nombres varchar(50) not null,
apellidos varchar(50) not null,
constraint pk_experto primary key(idExperto)


);


create table modificacion(

codModificacion varchar(50) not null,
modificacion varchar(200) not null,
constraint pk_mod  primary key(codModificacion)

);


create table estado_contrato(
codEstado varchar(50) not null,
estado varchar(50) not null,
pago money not null,
constraint pk_estado primary key(codEstado)

);

create table contrato(
codContrato varchar(50) not null,
fechaInicioConstruccion date not null,
duracionTotalConstruccion int not null,
codPedido varchar(50) not null,
idExperto varchar(50) not null,
codEstado varchar(50)not null,

constraint pk_contratoId primary key(codContrato),
constraint fk_pedidos foreign key(codPedido)
references pedido(codPedido) on update cascade on delete cascade,
constraint fk_experto foreign key(idExperto)
references experto(idExperto) on update cascade on delete cascade,
constraint fk_estado foreign key( codEstado)
references estado_contrato(codEstado) on update cascade on delete cascade 

);



create table modificaciones_contrato(
codModificacion varchar(50) not null,
codContrato  varchar(50) not null,
fechaMod date,
constraint pk_modificacion primary key(codModificacion,codContrato),
constraint fk_modif foreign key(codModificacion)
references modificacion(codModificacion) on update cascade on delete cascade,
constraint fk_contratoCod foreign key(codContrato)
references contrato(codContrato) on update cascade on delete cascade 


);

--MIGUEL 

create table operario(
codOperario varchar(50) not null,
nombreOperario varchar(50) not null,
constraint pk_operarioCod primary key(codOperario)
);

create table tipoOperario(
idTipoOperario varchar(50) not null,
tipoOperario varchar(50) not null,
constraint pk_TipoOperarioId primary key(idTipoOperario)
)

create table hojaCosto(
codHoja varchar(50) not null,
codContrato varchar(50) not null,

montoPlantas money not null,
montoAdornos money not null,
montoTierra money not null,
montoAbono money not null,
montoOperario money not null,
constraint pk_hojaCod primary key(codHoja),
constraint fk_contratoCodHoja foreign key(codContrato)
references contrato(codContrato) on update cascade on delete cascade,
);

create table detalleContrato(
codContrato varchar(50) not null,
cantidadPlantas int not null,
cantidadAdornos int not null,
tipoTierra varchar(50) not null,
cantidadTierra int not null, 
constraint pk_detalleContrato primary key(codContrato),
constraint fk_contratoCod2 foreign key(codContrato) 
references contrato(codContrato) on update cascade on delete cascade,
);

create table detalleContrato_Operar(
codContrato varchar(50) not null,
codOperario varchar(50) not null,
sueldo money not null,
constraint pk_detalleContrato_Operar primary key(codContrato,codOperario),
constraint fk_contratoCod3 foreign key(codContrato)
references contrato(codContrato) on update cascade on delete cascade,
constraint fk_contratoCod_Operario foreign key(codOperario) 
references operario(codOperario) on update cascade on delete cascade,
);



create table Tipo_Abono(
idTipoAbono varchar(50) not null, 
tipoAbono varchar(50) not null,
constraint pk_TipoAbonoId primary key(idTipoAbono),
);

create table abono(
codAbono varchar(50) not null,
abono money not null,
idTipoAbono varchar(50) not null,
precioUnidad int not null,
constraint pk_abonoCod primary key(codAbono),
constraint fk_TipoAbonoId foreign key(idTipoAbono) 
references  Tipo_Abono(idTipoAbono) on update cascade on delete cascade,
);

create table abonoDetalle_Contrato(
codAbono varchar(50) not null,
codContrato varchar(50) not null,
cantidad int not null,
constraint pk_abonoDetalle_Contrato primary key(codAbono,codContrato),
constraint fk_abonoDetalle_Contrato foreign key(codAbono)
references abono(codAbono) on update cascade on delete cascade,
constraint fk_contratoCod_Operar foreign key(codContrato) 
references contrato(codContrato) on update cascade on delete cascade,
);
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu pregunta es solo una gran cantidad de create de una base de datos. Cual es el problema real, y contra cuales tablas se supone que este? asi como esta, no vas a obtener ninguna respuesta...

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.